# Payroll array printout

Tags: c++

I have done my best to clear out the errors in this program, but am still coming up with nothing. I have searched but haven't found a solution.

> Write a program that uses the following arrays:
>
> • empId: an array of seven long integers to hold employee identification numbers. The array should be initialized with the following numbers:
>
> 5658845 4520125 7895122 8777541 8451277 1302850 7580489
>
> • hours: an array of seven integers to hold the number of hours worked by each employee
>
> • payRate: an array of seven doubles to hold each employee’s hourly pay rate
>
> • wages: an array of seven doubles to hold each employee’s gross wages
>
> The program should relate the data in each array through the subscripts. For example, the number in element 0 of the hours array should be the number of hours worked by the employee whose identiﬁcation number is stored in element 0 of the empId array. That same employee’s pay rate should be stored in element 0 of the payRate array.
>
> The program should display each employee number and ask the user to enter that employee’s hours and pay rate. It should then calculate the gross wages for that employee (hours times pay rate) and store them in the wages array.
>
> After the data has been entered for all the employees, the program should display each employee’s identiﬁcation number and gross wages.
>
> Input Validation: Do not accept negative values for hours or numbers less than 15.00 for pay rate.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //constant 
    const int empId = 7;
    //arrays initialized with manual entries
    int workers[empId] = { 5658845, 4520125, 7895122,
        8777541, 8451277, 1302850,
        7580489 };
    int hours[empId];
    double payRate[empId];

    //outputs for user entries
    cout << "Please enter the hours worked by " << empId
        << " employees and their\n"
        << "hourly pay rates.\n";
    //loops for each employee
    for (int index = 0; index < empId; index++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the hours worked by employee number " << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << workers[index] << ") : ";
        cin >> hours[index];
        cout << "Please enter the pay rate for employee number " << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << workers[index] << ") : ";
        cin >> payRate[index];
    }
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter the hours worked by employee number " << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << workers[index] << ") : ";
        cin >> hours[index];
    }
    if (hours[index] < 0); //data validation
    {
        cout << "Enter in a positive number" << endl;
    }
    while
    {
        (hours[index] < 0)

    do

        cout << "Please enter the pay rate for employee number " << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << workers[index] << ") : ";
        cin >> payRate[index];
    }
    if (payRate[index] < 15)  //data validation for pay rate
    {
        cout << "The pay rate must be >= 15" << endl;
    }
    //outputs for reults
    while (hours[index] < 6);
    {
        cout << "This is the gross pay for each employee:\n";
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < empId; index++)
    {
        double grossPay = hours[index] * payRate[index];
        cout << "Employee #" << (index + 1);
        cout << ": earned $" << grossPay << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats are the errors? You have a `do` floating in the air, I bet thats one of them

Comment: (Comment Edit: I guessed your error was a compilation error). Appart of the `do` floating in the air, you're using the variable `index` outside the `for`, and it is declared in the init-statment of the `for`

Comment: one important tip: dont write a wall of code just to struggle fixing the bugs. The opposite is a bit extreme but definitely less stressful: write a single line, compile, fix in case of an error, write the next line

Answer (score 2):

There are syntax errors in your `do` loops.

And you are not following your assigment's requirements:

- your `workers` array needs to be named `empId` instead
- you are missing a `wages` array
- you are not validating the user's input correctly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //constant 
    const int numEmployees = 7;

    //arrays initialized with manual entries
    int empId[numEmployees] = { 5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489 };
    int hours[numEmployees];
    double payRate[numEmployees];
    double wages[numEmployees];

    //inputs for user entries
    cout << "Please enter the hours worked by " << numEmployees << " employees\n"
         << "and their hourly pay rates.\n";

    //loops for each employee
    for (int index = 0; index < numEmployees; index++)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the hours worked by Employee # " << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << empId[index] << ") : ";
            if (cin >> hours[index])
            {
                if (hours[index] > 0) //data validation
                    break;

                cout << "Enter in a positive number" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cin.clear();
                cout << "Enter in a valid number" << endl;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the pay rate for Employee # " << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << empId[index] << ") : ";
            if (cin >> payRate[index])
            {
                if (payRate[index] >= 15.0)
                    break;

                cout << "The pay rate must be >= 15" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cin.clear();
                cout << "Enter in a valid monetary value" << endl;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        wages[index] = hours[index] * payRate[index];
    }

    //outputs for results

    cout << "This is the gross pay for each employee:\n";
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    for (int index = 0; index < numEmployees; index++)
    {
        cout << "Employee #" << (index + 1) << " (ID = " << empId[index] << ") : ";
        cout << "earned $" << wages[index] << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am still learning and the tutoring center is all but nonexistent here at the school but I will use this to learn from.